# How to transpose Columns to rows (with interruptions) in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

**Suppose that we have two columns including a million rows
like this:**

[image: 1]

**What is the right formula or VBA to make another arranged table like this?**

[image: 2]

Comment: What have you tried? examples would help other avoid things that don't work. One thing that springs to mind is "are all the keywords in red?" If so, then perhaps search between keywords based on colour. If they are not in red, then is there a "key" or list of the keywords?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The red texts was just because to pay more attention. I edited pix due to your concern. We need just to transpose each set of data to beside.

Comment: Two questions. Is there a known hard limit on the number of extra columns you need to create? And do you need a pure Excel answer or would a VBA solution be acceptable?

Comment: Why have you tagged the question with `interrupted-exception`? Such an exception would be thrown if a thread gets interrupted in a multithreading environment. VBA is not multi-threaded, and apparently you do not even want to use VBA. So what's with that tag?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake. I edited the tags.
If the only way is a VBA solution I'm eager to see it. I will learn how to use VBA. Thanks for your help

Comment: JohnTopley suggested: `=IF(AND(NOT(ISNUMBER($B2)),ISNUMBER(INDEX($B$2:$B$14,COLUMNS‌​($C:C)+COUNTA($B$1:$‌​B2)-1))),INDEX($A$2:‌​$A$14,COLUMNS($C:C)+‌​COUNTA($B$1:$B2)-1),‌​"")`
 But it works just for one row. I have a million rows

Comment: @xarxziux Yes we have 12 extra columns. VBA will be OK too.

Comment: @Sushiant With that much data, I wonder if you will need the 64 bit version of Excel, or perhaps consider a real DB solution

Comment: I have the 64 bit version of 2016 and an 8 mgb cash CPU and 16 gig of RAM. I also disabled the win 10 animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pure Excel solution try this.

First you need to add a helper column.  This just returns TRUE on a header row or FALSE otherwise.  This isn't *strictly* necessary, but it will make the rest of the formulas a little simpler.  In the sample you provided above, type this into cell C1:

```
=IF(A1=B1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Now enter this is cell D1:

```
=IF(AND(C1,NOT(C2)),A2,"")
```

What this does is check if the current row is a header but not the next, and copies the first cell of the next row if it is, or returns a blank string if it isn't.

Each subsequent cell follows the same pattern, but it first checks if the previous cell is blank.  Enter this function into cell E1:

```
=IF(D1="","",IF(AND(C1,NOT(C3)),A3,""))
```

Now you just need to copy this pattern outfor another 10 cells.  Unfortunately copy-and-paste won't work as you need to increment A3 and C3 downwards, while copy-and-paste with increment them to the right.  So, from E1, we get:

```
F1: =IF(E1="","",IF(AND(C1,NOT(C4)),A4,""))
G1: =IF(F1="","",IF(AND(C1,NOT(C5)),A5,""))
.
.
.
O1: =IF(N1="","",IF(AND(C1,NOT(C13)),A13,""))
```

Now copy those cells to the bottom of the data set and you should get the results you're after.  Here's an example:

[image: Completed example]

Note the extra TRUE in cell C21 so that the last calculation terminates correctly.

However, if you really have a million rows in your data set, I would question the wisdom of using Excel at all.  Depending on your circumstances and resources, you may be better off keeping the data in a text file and processing it with a proper scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved in excelforum by JohnTopley here:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1174447-interrupted-transpose.html